# Делать хорошую мину при плохой игре

Tags: этимология, омонимы

Если я правильно понимаю эту поговорку, под словом "мина" подразумевается выражение лица. То есть у игрока плохие карты, но на лице это у него никак не отражается, даже напротив, он придает себе довольное выражение.
Но мне интересно, почему по отношению к лицу, даже, скорее, гримасе, говорят "мина"? И как это слово связано с миной-оружием? Это просто омонимы или у слов общее происхождение? Было бы очень интересно узнать.

Answer (score 1):

В русском - просто омонимы. Хотя оба значения, судя по всему, восходят к французскому (а из него и к английскому) mine с набором значений с гнездом "копать", "рыть" и т.п.

Тут вот какая штука, в языке, куда слова приходят (языке-мишени) разными путями и  с разными значениями, их вполне логично считать чистыми омонимами, даже если они восходят к одному слову в языке-источнике. Этот язык-источник - другая "епархия", туда языку, позаимствовавшему слово, соваться со своими понятиями не след, а то так можно дойти до такой истории, в которой вообще все слова родственны, а смысла в том никакого.

Поэтому - эти слова считаются омонимами. Причем менее ныне распространенное значение появилось во французском едва ли не раньше.

А вообще история просматривается такая. "Миной" в военном деле едва ли не с XV века назывался ход, шахта, в которую потом закладывалось взрывчатое вещество (порох). Тут понятно, откуда значение "рыть". Потом это название перешло на сам заряд, позднее - на устройство его содержащее. При этом есть еще ряд сходных значений, менее употребительных и устаревающих, включая исходное "подкоп". Кстати, у филологов мина, которую закапывают, и мина-снаряд ("выстрел") обычно считаются *разными* значениями. Почему - не знаю, это уже не наш уровень, так уж сложилось.

Что де касается мины-гримасы, то оно полностью соответствует французскому значению и появилось в русском, видимо, в период массового увлечения французским - XVIII-XIX век.

Исследовать родство значений во французском мне не по силам, но что-то подсказывает, что там-то это созвучие не случайно. Впрочем, французский - совсем не моя стихия.
(+)
да, обнаружил, что у Фасмера есть некоторое развитие темы, но это уже на любителя, по сути ничего не добавляет к сказанному, только претендует на посредство немецкого в обоих случаях. 
//----
Слово: мина

Ближайшая этимология: I. "минный заряд, подкоп", начиная с эпохи Петра I; см. Смирнов 196. Через нов.-в.-н. Мine "подземный ход" (с 1600 г.; см. Шульц--Баслер 2, 115) или из франц. minе -- то же, кельт. происхождения; см. Гамильшег, ЕW 613; Клюге-ГеЁтце 392. Не исключено посредство польск. minа (см. Смирнов, там же).

Страницы: 2,622-623

Слово: мина

Ближайшая этимология: II. "выражение лица" (Гоголь). Через нем. Мiеnе (с XVII в.; см. Шульц--Баслер 2, 109) или прямо из франц. minе -- то же (о котором см. Гамильшег, ЕW 613).

Страницы: 2,623
//---
http://vasmer.narod.ru/p407.htm

Comment: Поскольку администрация считает, что характеристика "ахинея" (а другой у меня нету) обижает автора и рекомендует пользоваться кнопкой минус, мне ничего не остается, как воспользоваться этим советом.
(13 часов назад)behemothus

я вам это напоминать буду при каждом вашем выступлении, поскольку за отсебятину и плюсика жалко, да и минусика тоже.
вам плюсик, минусик за разбор и за ваше "ахинея" без обсуждения. А топор вам шею уже натер, не так ли?

А это чистая калька с французского "faire bonne mine a mauvais jeu"  где mine-
мое, я сам.  А в бретонском дословно--лицо.
Успехов вам в толковании мин